# Dynamic index of array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I;m new on Vuejs and I'm currently working with composition API so I have an array like this:

```
const tabs = ref([
      {
        id: 1,
        pdf: 'name1',
        ...
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        pdf: 'name2',
       ...
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        pdf: 'name3',
        ...
      },
    ])
```

Then I have a div like this:

```
<div
        v-for="tab in tabs"
        :key="tab.name"
        :href="tab.href"
        class="px-12 pt-8 flex flex-col"
        :class="[tab.current || 'hidden']"
        @click="changeTab(tab)"
      >
        <div v-if="pdf != ''">
          <div class="pt-4 font-bold underline">
            <a :href="pdfSrc" target="_blank">See PDF</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And then I use computed to get current href value as:

```
 props: {
    tabs: {
      type: Array as PropType<Array<any>>,
      required: true,
    },
  },



computed: {
    pdfSrc(): string {
          return `/img/modal/pdf/${encodeURIComponent(this.tabs[0].pdf)}.pdf`
        },
    }
```

As you can see I always use `tabs[0]` so pdf value is always value `name1` and I want to get depending of the selected tab

The tab method:

```
setup(props) {
  

    const changeTab = (selectedTab: { id: number }) => {
      props.tabs?.map((t) => {
        t.id === selectedTab.id ? (t.current = true) : (t.current = false)
      })
    }

    return {
      changeTab,
    }
  },
```

How can I change static index 0 to dynamic one depending on the current tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new variable for tracking the selected tab.

```
const selectedTabId = ref(0);
```

Similar to `tabs`, this could be passed down in array and the value updated in `changeTab` function.

```
props: {
 tabs: {
  type: Array as PropType<Array<any>>,
  required: true,
 },
 selectedTabId: {
     type: Number
  }
},


setup(props) {

const changeTab = (selectedTab: { id: number }) => {
   selectedTabId = selectedTab.id
  props.tabs?.map((t) => {
    t.id === selectedTab.id ? (t.current = true) : (t.current = false)
  })
}

  return {
   changeTab,
  }
 },
```

Finally in the computed use `selectedTabId`

```
computed: {
   pdfSrc(): string {
      return `/img/modal/pdf/${encodeURIComponent(this.tabs[this.selectedTabId].pdf)}.pdf`
    },
 }
```

Comment: I tried to declare constant, then assign in function but it is returning an error: Cannot assign to selectedTabId because it is a constant

Comment: Ohh, it is beacuse I do not use generics so it is  selectedTabId.value = selectedTab.id, excellent answer, thanks!